# How does Javascript evaluate the right parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a calculator that takes an expression such as `(5+4)` and evaluates it by passing the buttons pressed to an array, and then building a parse tree from the data in the array.

What's interesting/strange, is that my code won't push the value of the right parenthesis to the array. Here is my code, could someone help me out?

The console.log activeButton shows that is the value of the button being pressed, but even when I placed `calcArray.push()` outside the if statements it would not push ) to an array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var calcArray = new Array();

        $("input").click(function(){
            var activeButton = this.value;
            console.log(activeButton);
            if(!isNaN(activeButton))
            {
                calcArray.push(parseInt(activeButton));
                console.log(calcArray);
            }
            else if(activeButton === "=")
            {
                evaluate(buildTree(calcArray));
                calcArray = [];
            }
            else
            {
                calcArray.push(activeButton);
            }
        });
    });
```

The BuildTree code:

```
function BinaryTree(root) {
    this.root = root;
    this.activeNode = root;
}

function Node(element){
    this.element = element;
    this.parent;
    this.rightChild;
    this.leftChild;

    this.setLeft = function(node){
        this.leftChild = node;
        node.parent = this;
    };

    this.setRight = function(node){
        this.rightChild = node;
        node.parent = this;
    };
}


//methods

var buildTree = function(array)
{
    var tree = new BinaryTree(new Node(null));
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var newNode = new Node(array[i]);
        if(array[i] == "(")
        {
            newNode.element = null;
            tree.activeNode.setLeft(newNode);
            tree.activeNode = newNode;
        }
        else if(array[i] == "+" || array[i] == "-" || array[i] == "/" || array[i] == "*")
        {
            tree.activeNode.element = newNode.element;
            tree.activeNode.setRight(new Node(null));
            tree.activeNode = tree.activeNode.rightChild;
        }
        else if(array[i] == ")")
        {
            if(tree.activeNode.parent == null)
            {
            ;
            }
            else
            {
                tree.activeNode = tree.activeNode.parent;
                tree.root = tree.activeNode;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tree.activeNode.element = newNode.element;
            tree.activeNode = tree.activeNode.parent;
        }
    }
    return tree.activeNode;
}

var evaluate = function(node){
    var newNode1, newNode2;
    newNode1 = new Node(null);
    newNode1.parent = node;
    newNode2 = new Node(null);
    newNode2.parent = node;
    if(node.leftChild == null && node.rightChild == null)
        return node.element;
    else{
        newNode1.element = evaluate(node.leftChild);
        newNode2.element = evaluate(node.rightChild);
        if(newNode1.parent.element == "+")
        {
            return Number(newNode1.element) + Number(newNode2.element);
        }
        if(newNode1.parent.element == "-")
        {
            return newNode1.element - newNode2.element;
        }
        if(newNode1.parent.element == "*")
        {
            return newNode1.element * newNode2.element;
        }
        else
        {
            return newNode1.element / newNode2.element;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `)` has a special magic property that prevents it from being pushed into an array.

Comment: can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: If your `buildTree` function is not working properly, then please post its source (and some example arguments), not the invoking code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this out using your code and it worked fine passing the value as a string:

```
function pushButton (value) {
    var activeButton = value;
    console.log(activeButton);
    if(!isNaN(activeButton))
    {
        calcArray.push(parseInt(activeButton));
        console.log(calcArray);
    }
    else if(activeButton === "=")
    {
        evaluate(buildTree(calcArray));
        calcArray = [];
    }
    else
    {
        calcArray.push(activeButton);
    }
};
```

You aren't ever printing out the array in the last case (which is where the right paren would go), so are you sure it's not on the array and you just aren't seeing the visual feedback?

If so, we need to see more of your code. Try and setup a jsfiddle.

Comment: ugh, it was a matter of visual feedback. I tried it again this morning and it worked fine. Too much staring at the screen and not enough thinking through my code